# How do I add a separate div to "about me"?

Tags: support, profile-page, markdown

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) profile page:

[image: profile page]

There don't seem to be clear instructions on how to get the "div" with bullet points and links in the formatting he has. Is this a feature for only veteran users? Or am I just missing something?

**Update:** Specifically, I'm looking at how that section of "about me" is a different color, and how he can get the lines with and without bullet points to align with each other.

Comment: looks like they're using a quote block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div is on your profile edit page in the "about me" section.

Click on your username, then the "edit" link (kinda top-right).

You can use markup in that div with this little icons just above the text-field. Thus you can obtain your own bullet points and links...

**Update:**
inspecting the source-code of his about-me section we have:

The coloured section is a blockquote.  Inside of the blockquote is a list, and the markup for each list item is:

```
<li>
    Text
    <br><a href="...">Link</a>
</li>
```

Have a go at that and see if it gives you the results you need.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but I'm asking how that part of the about section is in a different color as well? Plus I can't get the formatting where the line with the bullet and the line without directly below it are aligned.

Comment: :) Ok - I'm pretty sure you can also use limited amounts of html in that section... so I'd guess having a play with that and seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I found a link with the supported HTML tags, but I didn't find anything that could help me create a sectioned off box, like he has. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 5):

The "About Me" section accepts Markdown as any post. The different background color is simply what a Markdown quote uses.

> - This is a list made of three items
> - This is the second one
>     This is the second line of the second item
> - This is the last one

This is what I wrote to get the previous output.

```
> - This is a list made of three items 
> - This is the second one  
   This is the second line of the second item
> - This is the last one
```

Answer (score 3):

They're just using a quote block.

```
This would be the normal colour.

> This would have darker background.
```

---

This would be normal colour.

> This would have darker background.